# VB.Net Hyperlinking in EWS email with class properties

Tags: vb.net, class, hyperlink, exchangewebservices

I need help getting the hyperlink to work as well as getting the value stored in `YestFile.FileName` to show up.

I have a list of objects of class `FileFromYesterday` (`Collection2`) with 3 properties. Two properties are just Strings (`FileName` and `Entity`) but one property (`URL`) contains a URL as a String. I am trying to hyperlink the URL to `FileName` in the main.

I have a feeling that I need to use HTML to format the email somehow but I have no Idea where to begin

```
 Dim HyperLink As String
        Dim FileLine As String
        Dim NewBody As String
        Dim message As New EmailMessage(EWS)
        message.Subject = "Monthly Financial Imported into Docushare on " & String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", Yesterday)
        NewBody = "Total of " & Collection2.Count & " Files Imported." & "\n"

        For Each YestFile In Collection2
            HyperLink = <a href="YestFile.URL">YestFile.FileName.Replace(".pdf", "")</a>
            FileLine = HyperLink & "Entity: " & YestFile.Entity & Environment.NewLine
            NewBody = NewBody & FileLine

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a HTML document in your NewBody varible so you need the pre and post tags for a HTML document eg

```html
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

the body content you want should go within between the Body Tags and for thing like NewLines you need to use the appropriate HTML tags such as

```
<br />
```

Eg what ever you end up creating in you NewBody variable you should be able to write out to a file or test in any Online HTML validator https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to see if its valid and how it will look before trying to send it.